# Error while shutting down 'Admin Server' from weblogic enterprise management console

Tags: oracle, weblogic, administration

I am using Weblogic Server em console to restart a webserver, URL looks like this:

http://localhost:7001/em/

AdminServer is named 'AdminServer', I wish to restart this server instance,

I click on server in EM console then user menu option like this:
(Weblogic server>Control>Shut Down...) I get this error:

'No Machine associated with server AdminServer. Please associate a machine to this weblogic server using weblogic console first.'

Not able to understand what this means....

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Oracle WebLogic, a *Machine* represents... well, a physical machine (and you can associate *Servers* i.e. WebLogic instances to it). This is not a fundamental concept except when using Node Managers. In general, you create *Machine(s)*, *Server(s)* and their association with the configuration wizard at domain creation time.

It is however possible to add a *Machine* from the console (**Environment > Machines > New**):

[image]

But you can't add a RUNNING *Server* to a *Machine* with the console, which will be a problem for the admin *Server*. So, I'd recommend to use the [configuration wizard](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13179_01/common/docs103/confgwiz/startcw.html) to extend your existing domain and add *Machine(s)*.

Note that all this will only solve the "shutdown problem", restarting will involve [Node Manager](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/nodemgr/starting_nodemgr.html#wp1069852) which is very likely not configured.